# Why can I only paint over specific areas of my model?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have done a UV project, and I have a texture applied to my model (I think). But when I paint somewhere, it paints in other places.

[image: example image]

Comment: Your second image did not show up because you edited out the URL for it.

Answer (score 2):

Smart UV project sometimes doesn’t work too great, and this is a perfect example. You need to mark seams and create your own UV map. There are many questions/answer pairs on this site, tutorials on YouTube, and even information in the docs to help you get this done.

Comment: I marked seams and created my own UV map, but nothing changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your UVs are basically wrong.
The UV islands are way too close from each other. So when you paint somewhere, it overflows on other parts.
It also badly uses the UV space, you literally have half of your pixels unused for no good reason.

The solution is just that : make a good UV map, that uses the UV space correctly and gives enough space between islands so that painting doesn't overlap.

Unfortunately, there is no specific tutorial to make a "good UV", because each model is different. Once you know the basic UV tools, it's a matter of trial and error until you get something that works and get some experience out of it.

I advise you to work use Blender's Color gird textures when working on UVs, it will show you what areas need more pixels and where you have deformations:

[image: uv example]